# IE6 and IE7 floating bug inside a header

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, css-float

We have an anchor tag floating right inside a header issue. It works fine on IE8 and Firefox.

Any idea how to stop it popping outside the header box?

Here is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .wrapper { border: 1px solid black; }
    .wrapper h3 a { float: right; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<h3>Contact Details
    <a href="#" class="action button">Update</a>
</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the right floated element first.

```
<h3><a href="#" class="action button">Update</a>Contact Details</h3>
```

Comment: I wish there was a more elegant solution, but this does resolve the problem. See example - http://jsfiddle.net/h5Zmu/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are floating it you need to tell the h3 to clear it. I assume this would work:

```
.wrapper h3 { overflow:hidden; zoom:1; }
```

LMK if not. And FYI, I wouldn't put the anchor inside of the h3 like that. I would probably make it a sibling of the h3, if necessary wrap a div around both and then apply the overflow/zoom.

Comment: This does stop it popping out of the box, but the header is pushed to the top of the box and the link pushed to the bottom.

Comment: Are you hiding some CSS? Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Here are two extra rules that I added in

```
.wrapper h3 { overflow:hidden; zoom:1; } 
.wrapper h3 a { margin: -1em 0 0 0; }
```